# Inserting an entry to JSON column in postgres

Tags: php, mysql, json, postgresql, codeigniter

I have a JSON entry like this, which I need to enter into a column (called values)

```
["Price Descending","Price Ascending","Name Ascending","Date Descending"]
```

How can I enter this into a json column , what I am trying is this (I am using CodeIgniter)

```
 $this->db->query("
       INSERT INTO tag_sets (type, value) VALUES
            ('sorting_options', " 
            'Price Descending', 'Price Ascending', 'Name Ascending', 
            'Date Descending'";
      ");
```

This gives me an error, what is the correct way to insert into a json column?

Comment: What error are you receiving? Do you also want to store it as the raw JSON or does it need to be another format?

Comment: Are you trying to insert all of those into one row? Or do you want each value to be a new row?

Comment: raw JSON, just in this format `["Price Descending","Price Ascending","Name Ascending","Date Descending"]`

Comment: one row `type` will be `sorting_options` and in `value` the json entry

Comment: You're going to have to do some quote escaping.  Or better, use bound parameters.

Comment: @PatrickQ Do I need the `DO $$` thing here? If so, how can I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `value` is a `json` column, you can convert the text representation of the array directly.

```
INSERT INTO tag_sets (type, value)
VALUES (
  'sorting_options',
  '["Price Descending","Price Ascending","Name Ascending","Date Descending"]'::json
);
```

You could also use a method to generate an array, depending on your situation.
Something like `json_build_array`.
More `json` methods can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: Doesn't work in the context of CI, `$this->db->query("`

Comment: If you want a double quote (`"`) within a string, you need to escape them. `" ... '[\"Price Descending\", ... "`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: I fail to see how on earth this code does not work and also fail to see why this answer was down voted.

Comment: Doesn't work man, doesn't work, can you try doing it within `$this->db->query("` first?

Comment: how can you know that this answer is useless, just because you fail to integrate this in Codeigniter because of your lack of knowledge how to handle a simple string...

Comment: of course it's useless, depends on the CONTEXT, this DOES NOT work with Codeigniter, hence, the above code is USELESS

Comment: @Cowgirl: Look up how to pass parameters into a query with CodeIgniter. “Escaped characters” are always the wrong way to do it and if this has been your strategy for past queries you’re probably vulnerable to SQL injection and have a lot of rewriting to do.